# Order by with more than 1 of lenght

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting weird results from this query:

```
SELECT id, nivel, tipo, titulo, texto, ativa 
FROM quests_faq 
ORDER BY nivel ASC;
```

The result should be like this:

```
5
10
15
20
40
50
55
etc..
```

Instead, it is sorting only by the first number:

```
10
15
2
30
40
5
55
etc
```

My row "nivel" contains only integers.
How can I use order in this case for the purpose I want?

Comment: It seems the data type of Nivel is CHAR, not a number and it is being sorted lexicographically

Comment: Yup, that was it, the row was has varchar, not int.    Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query may do what you are looking for by converting nivel into a number

```
SELECT id, nivel, tipo, titulo, texto, ativa
FROM quests_faq
ORDER BY CONVERT( nivel, INTEGER) ASC
```

Comment: Or just nivel+0, but probably best to use the correct data type

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be helpful:

```
SELECT id, nivel FROM quests_faq ORDER BY CAST(id as CHAR(13)) ASC
```

Cheers!